# How to setup my account bank to payment method for Magento?

Tags: magento, magento-1.9

I know how to setup a PayPal account, but in my country there is no PayPal, we pay through credit card. How I connect my website to my bank account if users pay through credit card?

Comment: can you precise more about the bank ? many have a specific system...

Comment: it's an online shop, the company has an account in a local bank in my country, I can merge this system with Magento?, or I have to work with PayPal or skrill app? I mean when the user pay, how to the money transfer to the company account without using PayPal?

Comment: Does the bank have api ? do they have a Magento module ?

Comment: this is the procedure then , i have to ask the bank about an API or Magento module and if yes ?

Comment: The only way, is to open a bank account in another country:
- for instance, create a bank account in USA, but also you will have to create a Paypal Account linked to the bank account (usa). Then you could transfer that money to your local bank account.
I did that for a Colombian store.

Comment: If bank has module you'll have to configure. If they have api, you will have to develop.  What are bank and country ?

Comment: Bank : Audi , and Country : Lebanon

Comment: I also need to accomplish this requirement, Bank only provides API support. Is there any sample module to develop for this